# Password encryption methods in classic ASP

Tags: encryption, asp-classic

I am looking for a method to encrypt/decrypt password in classic ASP. Can someone please suggest to me which method is good to go and what are the possible ways to do this in classic ASP.

Comment: I know this already but there should a programming language you are using to build classic application.

Comment: @EmaadAli  Your question should likely be VBScript or JScript then.

Comment: Well you using vbscript or jsript?

Answer (score 14):

You can download this free Classic ASP/VBScript script here which encrypts a string to SHA-256, an industry standard one-way hash function:

http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2565

Most people don't decrypt a password once it has been encrypted. The idea is to store a non reversible, encrypted password in your DB, which in turn stops an attacker reading passwords if the manage to get to your DB. When somebody enters a password, you encrypt the users input and match it against the encrypted password in the DB.

But hashing alone is not secure enough. You have to add a SALT value to the password you want to hash, to make it unbreakable. Salt should be a random but unique password that gets added to the password before hashing, for example:

```
password = Request("password")
salt = "2435uhu34hi34"
myHashedPassword = SHA256_function(password&salt)
```

Comment: It should be noted that this example is using [a pepper, not a salt](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/04/properly-salting-passwords-case-against.html).

Comment: When hashing passwords a slow hash such as Bcrypt offers more protection than a fast hash such as SHA-256.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a class of functions for hashing passwords in Classic ASP. As well as a standard hashing function that uses MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384 or SHA512 and an auto-generated salt and optional pepper, there's also support for **Argon2**, **Bcrypt** and **PBKDF2**

The standard hashing function should work on most shared hosting servers, the rest require the installation of COM DLL's which I have created and uploaded to GitHub. Everything is outlined and demonstrated in this repository:

https://github.com/as08/ClassicASP.PasswordHashing

Answer (score 0):

I created a COM-interop DLL for this exact task--Classic ASP Password Hashing. Simply build, register the DLL and call it from ASP.  This is an early working version using AES256, I plan to add additional algorithm support in the future.

https://github.com/kingdango/SaltedHashPassword

Suggestions welcome!

Classic ASP Code Example

```
newPassword = "whatever-the-user-typed"

set passwordGenerator = Server.createObject("Kingdango.SaltedHashPassword.PasswordHash")
passwordGenerator.Password = newPassword
newPasswordSaltedHash = passwordGenerator.GetHashedPassword()
newPasswordSalt = passwordGenerator.Salt
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same thing. This whole concept of hashing passwords made me realize that some major websites out there must be using a decrypt method as well. How else can they email a lost password if they do not keep it in either clear text or have a method of decrypting it.

Edit: I think I found an answer [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/)—database column-level encryption.

Comment: Looking for a one-way hash myself, but in this case odds are the site is storing the password in plain text. I mean, they spend the time and effort to encrypt/decrypt the password in the database, but then send it in the clear via unencrypted e-mail channel? Yeah, I'm thinking they are storing them in the database with no encryption. Should make you feel very secure. :)